# Coffeescript Error: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'mydata.length')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

This code works normally on the view where the coffee_input hash is being passed to the coffeescript code

```
 #if coffee_input?
 if typeof coffee_input isnt "undefined"
   mydata = JSON.parse coffee_input
   for p in mydata by 1
     if $('#'+p.name).length
       .. do stuff
```

but on other pages I keep getting in the browser this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'mydata.length')
```

although I'm using typeof coffee_input isnt `undefined`

I don't get it.

Edit: 
Code from View:

```
= javascript_tag do
  window.coffee_input = '#{raw @js.to_json}';
```

`@js` from the controller is:

```
   @js = []
   @js_hash = {"name" => p.name, "hosts" => "", "services" => ""}
   @js << @js_hash
```

Comment: `coffee_input` probably is not valid JSON. How about showing us what it is?

Comment: ah I didn't know it has to json, It should be json anyways.

Comment: Could you please log `mydata` ?

Comment: guys it works perfectly on the page it is supposed to load, but then on other pages where coffee_input doesn't exist it complains. I added the "typeof isn't defined" check but it's not working.

Comment: As long as ".. do stuff" isn't reassigning the coffee_input variable (and hence causing coffeescript to define it, making it's value null - which I don't expect it is, if it actually works for the page in which it's defined), then I think the other likely scenario is that coffee_input is being assigned the empty string ''. Why, exactly, aren't you using 'if coffee_input?' like you have commented out in the top line?

Comment: I tried that first and it didn't work. it works perfectly the data are loaded on the page (the do stuff is actually drawing a bar chart) but then if click a link where I'm not sending the variable it complains "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'mydata.length')"... I'm looking at it thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I looked at the Javascript generated in the browser

```
(function() {
  jQuery(function() {
var context, g, metrics, mydata, overall, pod, _i, _len, _results;

if (typeof coffee_input !== "undefined" && coffee_input !== null) {
  mydata = JSON.parse(coffee_pods);
  _results = [];
  } // WRONG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  for (_i = 0, _len = mydata.length; _i < _len; _i += 1) {
      …..
```

For some unknown reason, it was putting the curly brace at the end of the if as opposed to the end of the for loop.

I just re-wrote it, spacing was correct, if it wasn't coffee script would've complained.

Comment: mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: It must be! this is so annoying.

Comment: since we're here: you could also rewrite that conditional as `unless coffee_input?`